# subquery has invalid column name yet results are returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

The subquery in this query is invalid. The program table contains no column named 'calcfile'. The correct column name is 'calc_file'.  However, when I ran the query, I got no error and the results were as though the where clause didn't exist. Shouldn't I have a gotten an error instead of invalid results?

```
select distinct result from calcdetl
where calcfile = (select calcfile from program where program = 'HIGLAS Program')
order by result
;
```

https://snag.gy/StPnqf.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is interpreted as:

```
select distinct cd.result
from calcdetl cd
where cd.calcfile = (select cd.calcfile from program p where p.program = 'HIGLAS Program')
order by cd.result;
```

And that is perfectly valid -- it is a correlated subquery.

Moral?  *Always* use qualified column names when your query refers to more than one table.

You would get an error if you had written:

```
select distinct cd.result
from calcdetl cd
where cd.calcfile = (select p.calcfile from program p where p.program = 'HIGLAS Program')
order by cd.result;
```